# Clarification about adding a method to an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the following function, with a method inside of it called `newlastname` :

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
  this.firstname=firstname;
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.age=age;
  this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

  this.newlastname=newlastname;
}


function newlastname(new_lastname)
{
  this.lastname=new_lastname;
}
```

In the line `this.newlastname=newlastname;` what is happening? What does the first  newlastname refer to? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
this.newlastname=newlastname;
```

The first `newlastname` is a property on the `person` object.

The second `newlastname` is a reference to the `newlastname()` function.

So, when you do this:

```
this.newlastname=newlastname;
```

you are storing a reference to that function in a property of the `person` object.  That would allow the following code to work:

```
var p = new person("Ted", "Smith", 31, "blonde");
p.newlastname("Bundy");
```

When you execute `p.newlastname("Bundy");`, it will look for a property on the `person` object called `newlastname`.  When it finds that property, it will execute that function and pass it `"Bundy"` and set `this` to be the particular `person` object.

Comment: Awesome - it clicked now! Thank You very Much!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `this.x = x` inside of an function (all functions are objects), the first x becomes a property of the object. So you can do `this.x` anywhere inside the object to access its value. example -

```
    function test (x)
    {
        this.x = x + 2; // the first x is an property of test. the second is the passed argument
        return this.x;
   }

   console.log(test(2)); // 4
```

you can also do the following to check all the properties and methods of test

```
console.log(new test(2));
```